# Content overlapping in Twitter Bootstrap V3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue where any content put into a column spills over into the one next to it.

An example of this is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8"><p>ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp</p></div>
<div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

The p's go into the col 4, I would have thought it would have gone onto the next line when it came to the end of the 8 columns it's supposed to span...

Am I missing something here??

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a general facet of HTML rendering. Where would you break the `p`'s? There is no logical place to break it, so it stays on one line.

The best that you could do is set the following:

```
.col-md-8 { overflow: hidden; }
```

which would hide the extra p's instead of having them overflow on the other content. This isn't an ideal solution because it makes the content unavailable versus just breaking the design.

The 8 columns just specifies a width for the bounding box of the `p` element. As much as possible, the content will fit that box, just content that is too big and can't be broken (also thinking of a very large image) will overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is

```
.break{ word-wrap: break-word;}
```

This will force a line to the break while overflow hidden simply hides the text.